# SharePoint Reserved Words

Tags: 2010

Get this error when creating a site containing 'record' in the name. Is the a list of reserved words that you can't use in SharePoint site names?

> Site names cannot contain certain reserved words and cannot begin with an underscore

**Correction**
Even though the error message was about 'site names', it was the fact the managed path was 'records', nothing to do with the site title. A misleading error message. However, I still would like to know what the reserved words are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just wanted to expand on Joelji's answer, since I recently ran into the same problem:

Any of the "Managed Paths" are restricted site names.  You can find this by going to [Central Administration] > [Application Management : Manage Web Applications] > Select a Web Application, and click [Managed Paths]

By default you will see [root] and "sites", and any inclusions someone added to the SC.  Although from reading this post and others, there are additional restricted site names like "search".  I don't know where those additional restrictions are stored.

From Powershell, you can also run:

```
Get-SPManagedPath -WebApplication "[Site URL]"
```

Comment: It still can't work. Let's check with the path "CON", "COM1", "LPRN"...

Answer (score 2):

I think "Personal" and "Sites" are reserved words, not sure if MS have a published list of what's not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

If the same site name is used as a site collection name already, you cannot create a site with the same name. 
In my case, I created a site collection with the same name using Managed path(explicit inclusion). After deleting, the site collection, delete the managed path too to create a site with the same name.